# How to split a DataFrame into multiple DataFrames by row value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below one. I want to split the Dataframe based on Rows

```
     Rows            col1    value1      value2
0    row_1            var1     12         3434           
1    row_1            var2     212       546        
2    row_1            var3     340       8686       
3    row_2            var1     226        55      
4    row_2            var2     323        878        
97   row_33           var1     592        565        
98   row_33           var2     282       343    
99   row_33           var3     455        764      
100  row_34           var1     457        24        
101  row_34           var2     617        422
```

expected Dataframes

Df1

```
     Rows            col1    value1      value2
0    row_1            var1     12         3434           
1    row_1            var2     212       546        
2    row_1            var3     340       8686
```

Df2

```
     Rows            col1    value1      value2
0    row_2            var1     226        55     
1    row_2            var2     323        878     
2    row_2            var3     453        78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the `'Rows'` and create a `dict` of `DataFrames` with unique `'Row'` values as keys, with a [`dict-comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

  - `.groupby` returns a `groupby` object, that contains information about the groups, where `g` is the unique value in `'Rows'` for each group, and `d` is the `DataFrame` for that group.
- The `value` of each `key` in `df_dict`, will be a `DataFrame`, which can be accessed in the standard way, `df_dict['key']`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup data and dataframe
data = {'Rows': ['row_1', 'row_1', 'row_1', 'row_2', 'row_2', 'row_33', 'row_33', 'row_33', 'row_34', 'row_34'],
        'col1': ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var1', 'var2', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var1', 'var2'],
        'value1': [12, 212, 340, 226, 323, 592, 282, 455, 457, 617],
        'value2': [3434, 546, 8686, 55, 878, 565, 343, 764, 24, 422]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# split the dataframe and loop of the groupby object
df_dict = dict()

for g, d in df.groupby('Rows'):
    df_dict[g] = d


# or as a dict comprehension: the unique Row value will be the key
df_dict = {g: d for g, d in df.groupby('Rows')}


# or a specific name for the key, using enumerate
df_dict = {f'df{i}': d for i, (g, d) in enumerate(df.groupby('Rows'))}
```

#### `df_dict['df0']` or `df_dict['row_1']`

```
    Rows  col1  value1  value2
0  row_1  var1      12    3434
1  row_1  var2     212     546
2  row_1  var3     340    8686
```

#### `df_dict['df1']` or `df_dict['row_2']`

```
    Rows  col1  value1  value2
3  row_2  var1     226      55
4  row_2  var2     323     878
```

#### `df_dict['df2']` or `df_dict['row_33']`

```
     Rows  col1  value1  value2
5  row_33  var1     592     565
6  row_33  var2     282     343
7  row_33  var3     455     764
```